Custom Success or Error message in the popup in Magento 2.4
I am creating the functionality for showing error or success messages in the custom popup box after order placement in Magento 2.4. Any reference or help is appreciated.

Please provide more information. Do you want the popup on checkout or on success page? Should it be shown with some delay?

After we press the place order button, then success or error message appears in the popup with order details like order number.

you can use this code to add popup on place order.
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/default.js
define([
    'ko',
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
    'Magento_Ui/js/model/messages',
    'uiLayout',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (
    ko,
    $,
    Component,
    placeOrderAction,
    selectPaymentMethodAction,
    quote,
    customer,
    paymentService,
    checkoutData,
    checkoutDataResolver,
    registry,
    additionalValidators,
    Messages,
    layout,
    modal
) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        redirectAfterPlaceOrder: true,
        isPlaceOrderActionAllowed: ko.observable(quote.billingAddress() != null),

        /**
         * After place order callback
         */
        afterPlaceOrder: function () {
            // Override this function and put after place order logic here
        },

        /**
         * Initialize view.
         *
         * @return {exports}
         */
        initialize: function () {
            var billingAddressCode,
                billingAddressData,
                defaultAddressData;

            this._super().initChildren();
            quote.billingAddress.subscribe(function (address) {
                this.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(address !== null);
            }, this);
            checkoutDataResolver.resolveBillingAddress();

            billingAddressCode = 'billingAddress' + this.getCode();
            registry.async('checkoutProvider')(function (checkoutProvider) {
                defaultAddressData = checkoutProvider.get(billingAddressCode);

                if (defaultAddressData === undefined) {
                    // Skip if payment does not have a billing address form
                    return;
                }
                billingAddressData = checkoutData.getBillingAddressFromData();

                if (billingAddressData) {
                    checkoutProvider.set(
                        billingAddressCode,
                        $.extend(true, {}, defaultAddressData, billingAddressData)
                    );
                }
                checkoutProvider.on(billingAddressCode, function (providerBillingAddressData) {
                    checkoutData.setBillingAddressFromData(providerBillingAddressData);
                }, billingAddressCode);
            });

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Initialize child elements
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initChildren: function () {
            this.messageContainer = new Messages();
            this.createMessagesComponent();

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Create child message renderer component
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        createMessagesComponent: function () {
            var messagesComponent = {
                parent: this.name,
                name: this.name + '.messages',
                displayArea: 'messages',
                component: 'Magento_Ui/js/view/messages',
                config: {
                    messageContainer: this.messageContainer
                }
            };

            layout([messagesComponent]);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Place order.
         */
        placeOrder: function (data, event) {
            var self = this;

            if (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }

            if (this.validate() &&
                additionalValidators.validate() &&
                this.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed() === true
            ) {
                this.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(false);

                this.getPlaceOrderDeferredObject()
                    .done(
                        function () {
                            self.afterPlaceOrder(response);

                            // Show popup instead of redirecting
                            self.showOrderSuccessPopup(response);

                        }
                    ).always(
                        function () {
                            self.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(true);
                        }
                    );

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        },

        /**
         * @return {*}
         */
        getPlaceOrderDeferredObject: function () {
            return $.when(
                placeOrderAction(this.getData(), this.messageContainer)
            );
        },

        /**
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        selectPaymentMethod: function () {
            selectPaymentMethodAction(this.getData());
            checkoutData.setSelectedPaymentMethod(this.item.method);

            return true;
        },

        isChecked: ko.computed(function () {
            return quote.paymentMethod() ? quote.paymentMethod().method : null;
        }),

        isRadioButtonVisible: ko.computed(function () {
            return paymentService.getAvailablePaymentMethods().length !== 1;
        }),

        /**
         * Get payment method data
         */
        getData: function () {
            return {
                'method': this.item.method,
                'po_number': null,
                'additional_data': null
            };
        },

        /**
         * Get payment method type.
         */
        getTitle: function () {
            return this.item.title;
        },

        /**
         * Get payment method code.
         */
        getCode: function () {
            return this.item.method;
        },

        /**
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        validate: function () {
            return true;
        },

        /**
         * @return {String}
         */
        getBillingAddressFormName: function () {
            return 'billing-address-form-' + this.item.method;
        },

        /**
         * Dispose billing address subscriptions
         */
        disposeSubscriptions: function () {
            // dispose all active subscriptions
            var billingAddressCode = 'billingAddress' + this.getCode();

            registry.async('checkoutProvider')(function (checkoutProvider) {
                checkoutProvider.off(billingAddressCode);
            });
        },

        /**
         * Show Order Success Popup
         */
        showOrderSuccessPopup: function(response) {
            // Create the modal HTML
            var modalHtml = `
                <div id="order-success-popup" class="modal" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <h1>Order Placed Successfully</h1>
                    <p>Your order id is: <strong>${response}</strong></p>
                        <p>Your order has been placed successfully!</p>
                        <button id="close-popup" class="action primary">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;

            // Append the modal HTML to the body
            $('body').append(modalHtml);

            // Initialize the modal
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: 'Order Placed Successfully',
                buttons: []
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#order-success-popup'));

            // Open the modal
            $('#order-success-popup').modal('openModal');

            // Close the modal on button click
            $('#close-popup').on('click', function() {
                $('#order-success-popup').modal('closeModal');
            });
        }
    });
});

Result will be like this.


After closing popup you can redirect to homepage , if need help let me know.

Can we add order details in the popup like its ID or increment id , and on closing the popup, it should redirect to home page

@MitulVadalia code is updated with order id in popup

To redirect  use this in close-popup
$('#close-popup').on('click', function() {
$('#order-success-popup').modal('closeModal');
window.location.href = urlBuilder.build(''); // Redirect to home page
});
